# When to use Datomic Upsert?

Tags: clojure, upsert, datomic

I'm referring to `:db/unique :db.unique/identity`
(as opposed to `:db.unique/value`)

Upsert to me in my naivety sounds a bit scary, because if i try to insert a new record which has the same value (for a field declared unique) for an existing record, my feeling is that I ***want*** that to fail.

What I'd do if a field is declared unique is, when creating or updating another record, check whether that value is taken, and if it is give the user feedback that it's taken.

What am i missing about upsert and when/why is it useful?

A search revealed the following (not in relation to datomic)

> "upsert helps avoid the creation of duplicate records and can save you time (if inserting a group) because you don't have to determine which records exist first".

What I dont' understand is that the datomic docs sometimes suggest using this, but I don't see why it's better in any way. Saving time at the cost of allowing collisions?

e.g., if I have a user registration system, I definitely do not want to "upsert" on the email the user submits. I can't think of a case when it would be useful - other than the one quoted above, if you had a large collection of things and you "didn't have time" to check whether they existed first.

Answer (score 3):

Datomic property `:db/unique` can be used with `:db.unique/identity` or `:db.unique/value`

If it's used with `:db.unique/identity`, will upsert

If used with `:db.unique/value`, will conflict.